# How can I use curl to login multiple users from one php script

Tags: php, curl

Here is the scenario:
I have configured multiple users with login names aa1, aa2 .. zz99 , all with the same password, now i want to login to a php based server with these login ID's. I have a working script that logs in one user with a username and password, and using curl, browses to a target page:

```
// Assume php , since somehow the php encapsulation quotes were giving me trouble

$sHost           = $argv[2];
$sStart          = $argv[3];
$sReqId          = $argv[4];
$sPage           = $argv[5];
$sReqLogFile     = $argv[6];
$sRespLogFile    = $argv[7];
$sUserName       = $argv[8];
$sPassword       = $argv[9];
$sExecDelay      = $argv[10];
//optional args:
if($argc > 11)

{
  $sCommonSID      = $argv[11];
}
//$sXhprofLogFile  = "";
$sSysStatsLogFile= "";
$sBaseUrl        = 'https://'.$sHost.'/';
$nExecTime       = 0;
$sCookieFileName = 'cookiejar/'.genRandomString().'.txt';
touch($sCookieFileName);


// Set the execution delay:
$sStart += $sExecDelay;


// Get the PHP Session Id:
if(isset($sCommonSID))
{
  $sSID = $sCommonSID;
}else{
  $sSID          = getSID($sHost,$sBaseUrl, $sUserName, $sPassword);
}


// Sleep for 100us intervals until we reach the stated execution time:
do
{
  usleep(100);
}while(getFullMicrotime()$sPage, 
                         "pageUrl"=>$sBaseUrl, 
    "execStart" =>$nExecStart,
                         "execEnd"=>$nExecEnd, 
                         "respTime"=>$nExecTime,
                         "xhprofToken"=>$sXhpToken,
                         "xhprofLink"=>$sXhpLink,
                         "fiveMinLoad"=>$nFiveMinLoad);
  }else{
    $nExecStart = 0;
    $sUrl = "***ERROR***";
    $aReturn = null;
  }
  writeReqLog($sReqId, $nExecStart, $sSID, $sUrl, $sReqLogFile);
  return $aReturn;
}


function getFullMicrotime()
{
  $fMtime             = microtime(true);
  if(strpos($fMtime, ' ') !== false)
  {
    list($nUsec, $nSec) = explode(' ', $fMtime);
    return $nSec + $nUsec;
  }
  return $fMtime;
}


function writeRespLog($nReqId, $sHost, $sPage, $sSID = "***ERROR***", $nExecStart = 0, $nExecEnd = 0, $nRespTime = 0, $sXhpToken = "", $sXhpLink = "", $nFiveMinLoad = 0, $sRespLogFile)
{
  $sMsg = $nReqId;
  $sMsg .= "\t".$sHost;
  $sMsg .= "/".$sPage;
  $sMsg .= "\t".$sSID;
  $sMsg .= "\t".$nExecStart;
  $sMsg .= "\t".$nExecEnd;
  $sMsg .= "\t".$nRespTime;
  $sMsg .= "\t".$sXhpToken;
  $sMsg .= "\t".$nFiveMinLoad;
  error_log($sMsg."\n",3,$sRespLogFile);
}


function writeReqLog($nReqId, $nExecStart, $sSID, $sUrl, $sReqLogFile)
{
  $sMsg = $nReqId;
  $sMsg .= "\t".$sUrl;
  $sMsg .= "\t".$sSID;
  $sMsg .= "\t".$nExecStart;
  error_log($sMsg."\n",3,$sReqLogFile);
}


function parseSIDValue($sText)
{
  $sSID         = "";
  preg_match('/SID:(.*)/',$sText, $aSID);
  if (count($aSID))
  {
    $sSID       = $aSID[1];
  }
  return $sSID;
}


function parseFiveMinLoad($sText)
{
  $nLoad      = 0;
  $aMatch     = array();
  preg_match('/--5-MIN-LOAD:(.*)--/',$sText, $aMatch);
  if (count($aMatch))
  {
    $nLoad    = $aMatch[1];
  }
  return $nLoad;
}


function curlRequest($sUrl, $sSID="")
{
  global $sCookieFileName;
  $ch = curl_init(); 
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $sUrl); 
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE); 
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 2); 
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1); 
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.0)"); 
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1); 
  if($sSID == "")
  {
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, $sCookieFileName);
  }
  else
  {
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, $sCookieFileName);
  }
  $result =curl_exec ($ch); 
  curl_close ($ch); 
  return $result;
}


function parseXHProfToken($sPageContent)
{
  //https://ktest.server.net/xhprof/xhprof_html/index.php?run=4d004b280a990&source=mybox
  $sToken   = "";
  $sRelLink = "";
  $aMatch   = array();
  $aResp    = array();
  preg_match('/$sToken, "relLink"=>$sRelLink);
  return $aResp;
}


function genRandomString() {
  $length = 10;
  $characters = '0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz';
  $string = '';    
  for ($p = 0; $p
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems the code "snippet" you've found is a commandline script. To login with multiple accounts, you have to regroup the execution code (all from start to while loop) into a function like:

```
function login($sHost, $sStart,$sReqId, $sPage, $sReqLogFile,
               $sRespLogFile, $sUserName, $sPassword, $sExecDelay) {
```

Then loop over your users list, and call the function:

```
foreach ($users as $sUserName=>$sPassword) {
    login($sStupidArgNames...);
```